# Azure Data Factory project with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-data-factory

I am not sure whether Azure Data Factory project is supported on Visual Studio 2017 at the moment.

I have just installed VS 2017 but cannot open our solution as there is one azure data factory project.

[image]

Does Azure Data Factory support on Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: Just to follow up as the VS team still haven't sorted this out. I've created an MS feedback item to try and push it through that way. Please vote on it. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/18773008-support-adf-projects-in-visual-studio-2017 Thanks

Comment: What did you actually open here? AFAIK there is not such thing as an "Azure Data Factory Project"

Comment: @PaulAndrew The link is broken unfortunately. This feature is not available yet in VS even in 2022.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I tweeted the Visual Studio team with exactly this issue a couple of days ago. I even included a screen shot very similar to yours.

This is the response I got:

> @mrpaulandrew We have no info about it yet. Our team is already
>   working on this. Please stay tuned to our blog:
>   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/.

So to answer your question. **No, not at the moment.**

But hopefully very soon.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i hoped something might appear after msbuild... *sigh*

Comment: So did I. Please vote for it on MS feedback here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/18773008-support-adf-projects-in-visual-studio-2017

Comment: any time you are ready Microsoft... I am going to try to contact the product team

Comment: . . . any updates on the visual studio 2017 environment getting an update to cover azure data factory project authoring and debugging?

Answer (score 0):

The offline ADF project support in Visual Studio was discontinued. You need to use the online projects instead.