# how to create azure data factory project in vs2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-data-factory

how to create azure data factory in vs 2017?
I dont have vs2015, what can i do?
I checked for online template but cant find one.
similar questions is : [Azure Data Factory project with Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43001227/azure-data-factory-project-with-visual-studio-2017)
but it does not have answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Data Factory project with Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43001227/azure-data-factory-project-with-visual-studio-2017)

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no template for creating data factories using VS 2017.  The best you can do is install Visual Studio 2015 and then install the data factory tools

Comment: You can add your vote to the UserVoice issue for this [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/18773008-support-adf-projects-in-visual-studio-2017)